# JPype get numpy array from JArray

Tags: jpype

Is it possible to get a numpy array from a JArray of bytes?  I need access to the raw bytes and when i try:

```
numpy.frombuffer(jpype_object)
```

It stays:

```
AttributeError: 'byte[]' object has no attribute '__buffer__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like array slices does what i'm looking for:

https://github.com/originell/jpype/pull/73